# Unable to load tilesets and maps into my Phaser3 game

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework, tiled

I am new to phaser and game development.

I followed the below tutorial.

https://medium.com/@michaelwesthadley/modular-game-worlds-in-phaser-3-tilemaps-1-958fc7e6bbd6

I downloaded and Tiled software and made a simple map with a tileset I got from OpenGameArt.org. Unfortunately, nothing gets loaded on the browser screen, I just see a black rectangle instead of the map. I find no errors in the console. I am running this using XAMPP in Windows 10.

I will paste all my code here, let me know if you find anything wrong.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.15.1/dist/phaser-arcade-physics.min.js"> 
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The is the index.js file

```
const config = {
        type: Phaser.AUTO, // Which renderer to use
        width: 100, // Canvas width in pixels
        height: 100, // Canvas height in pixels
        parent: "game-container", // ID of the DOM element to add the canvas to
        scene: {
          preload: preload,
          create: create,
          update: update
        }
      };
      const game = new Phaser.Game(config);
      function preload() {
        // Runs once, loads up assets like images and audio
        this.load.image("tiles", "assets/tilesets/GoldBricks.png");
        this.load.tilemapTiledJSON("map", "assets/tilemaps/mario.json");
      }
      function create() {
        // Runs once, after all assets in preload are loaded
        const map = this.make.tilemap({ key: "map" });
        const tileset = map.addTilesetImage("GoldBricks", "tiles");
        // Parameters: layer name (or index) from Tiled, tileset, x, y
        const belowLayer = map.createStaticLayer("Tile Layer 1", tileset, 0, 0);
      }

      function update(time, delta) {
        // Runs once per frame for the duration of the scene
      }
```

EDIT: Below is the json file

```
  { "compressionlevel":-1,
 "height":100,
 "infinite":false,
 "layers":[
        {
         "compression":"",
         "data":"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABUAAAAWAAAAFwAAABgAAAAZAAAAFQAAABYAAAAXAAAAGAAAABkAAAAaAAAAFQAAABYAAAAXAAAAGAAAABkAAAAaAAAAFQAAABYAAAAXAAAAGAAAABkAAAAaAAAAFQAAABYAAAAXAAAAGAAAABkAAAAVAAAAFgAAABcAAAAYAAAAFQAAABYAAAAXAAAAGAAAABkAAAAaAAAAFQAAABYAAAAXAAAAGAAAABkAAAAaAAAAFQAAABYAAAAXAAAAGAAAABkAAAAaAAAAFQAAABYAAAAXAAAAGAAAABkAAAAaAAAAFQAAABYAAAAXAAAAGAAAABkAAAAaAAAAFQAAABYAAAAXAAAAGAAAABkAAAAaAAAAFQAAABYAAAAXAAAAGAAAABkAAAAaAAAAFQAAABYAAAAXAAAAGAAAABkAAAAaAAAAFQAAABYAAAAXAAAAGAAAABkAAAAaAAAAFQAAABYAAAAXAAAAGAAAABkAAAAaAAAAFQAAABYAAAAXAAAAGAAAABkAAAAaAAAAkQAAAJIAAADYAAAA2AAAANgAAADYAAAA2AAAANgAAADYAAAA2AAAANgAAADYAAAA2AAAANgAAADYAAAA2AAAANgAAADYAAAA2AAAANgAAADYAAAA2AAAANgAAADYAAAA2AAAANgAAADYAAAA2AAAANgAAADYAAAA2AAAANgAAADYAAAA2AAAANgAAADYAAAA2AAAANgAAADYAAAA2AAAANgAAADYAAAA2AAAANgAAADYAAAA2AAAANgAAADYAAAA2AAAANgAAADYAAAA2AAAANgAAADYAAAA2AAAANgAAADYAAAA2AAAANgAAADYAAAA2AAAANgAAADYAAAA2AAAANgAAADYAAAA2AAAANgAAADYAAAA2AAAANgAAADYAAAA2AAAANgAAADYAAAA2AAAANgAAADYAAAA2AAAANgAAADYAAAA2AAAANgAAADYAAAA2AAAANgAAADYAAAA2AAAANgAAADYAAAA2AAAANgAAADYAAAA2AAAANgAAADYAAAA2AAAANgAAADYAAAA2AAAANgAAADYAAAA2AAAANgAAADYAAAA2AAAANgAAADYAAAA2AAAANgAAADYAAAA2AAAANgAAADYAAAA2AAAANgAAADYAAAA2AAAANgAAADYAAAA2AAAANgAAADYAAAA2AAAANgAAADYAAAA2AAAANgAAADYAAAA2AAAANgAAADYAAAA2AAAANgAAADYAAAA2AAAANgAAADYAAAA2AAAANgAAADYAAAA2AAAANgAAADYAAAA2AAAANgAAADYAAAA2AAAANgAAADYAAAA2AAAANgAAADYAAAA2AAAANgAAADYAAAA2AAAANgAAADYAAAA2AAAANgAAADYAAAA2AAAANgAAADYAAAA2AAAANgAAADYAAAA2AAAANgAAADYAAAA2AAAANgAAADYAAAA2AAAANgAAADYAAAA2AAAANgAAADYAAAA2AAAANgAAADYAAAA2AAAANgAAADYAAAA2AAAANgAAADYAAAA2AAAANgAAADYAAAA2AAAANgAAADYAAAA2AAAANgAAADYAAAA2AAAANgAAADYAAAA2AAAAA==",
         "encoding":"base64",
         "height":100,
         "id":1,
         "name":"Tile Layer 1",
         "opacity":1,
         "type":"tilelayer",
         "visible":true,
         "width":100,
         "x":0,
         "y":0
        }],
 "nextlayerid":2,
 "nextobjectid":1,
 "orientation":"orthogonal",
 "renderorder":"right-down",
 "tiledversion":"1.3.2",
 "tileheight":32,
 "tilesets":[
        {
         "columns":16,
         "firstgid":1,
         "image":"..\/..\/..\/..\/..\/Users\/Shashank A C\/Downloads\/Goldbricksandgrass\/GoldBricks.png",
         "imageheight":512,
         "imagewidth":512,
         "margin":0,
         "name":"GoldBricks",
         "spacing":0,
         "tilecount":256,
         "tileheight":32,
         "tilewidth":32
        }],
 "tilewidth":32,
 "type":"map",
 "version":1.2,
 "width":100
}
```

I am also seeing and error in the console now.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
at StaticTilemapLayer.upload (phaser.js:74806)
at StaticTilemapLayerWebGLRenderer [as renderWebGL] (phaser.js:122959)
at WebGLRenderer.render (phaser.js:65133)
at CameraManager.render (phaser.js:114533)
at Systems.render (phaser.js:27184)
at SceneManager.render (phaser.js:46818)
at Game.step (phaser.js:109346)
at TimeStep.step (phaser.js:106091)
at step (phaser.js:66488)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I asked in the phaser community forum itself and got some help.
The tilemap layer is taller than the game canvas so the visible tiles are out of sight. The solution is to add the below code in the `create` function.

```
this.cameras.main.centerOn(800, 1300);
```

Answer (score 3):

UPDATE: Check this file structure -- 
https://next.plnkr.co/edit/OqywHzLC80aZMGeF

======

Need to see the JSON file to completely understand the issue, but I will just try to speculate. Make sure your JSON file has below settings correctly:

```
"tilesets":[
    {
        "image":"path/to/GoldBricks.png",
        "name":"GoldBricks"
        ...
    }
]
```

In some cases Tiled includes wrong/different path to the image file, so make sure to check that part. If there is no image path, embed it in Tiled.

In addition, the `name` value should match the first parameter of `map.addTilesetImage()`. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the response ! I have updated the question with the json file, it does seem to have what you said.

Comment: @ShashankAC I quickly tested it and see two potential issues:
1. Your `tilesets.image` path should be something like `../tilesets/GoldBricks.png`. Currently it shows your `Download` folder path on your mac.
2. After fixing the path, now the error msg says the encoding is corrupted. Try Tiled (https://www.mapeditor.org/) to create your own map. Unfortunately, I have no idea how to fix corrupted map encodings.

I created a folder structure for you in my updated answer above, go check it out (not working due to map error). Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for trying, I am not sure, but do you think that big string value the for the key `data` should actually be an array of arrays ? something like [[A, A, A...], ] like the simple example given in the medium article I linked to ?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem myself, the solution was going back to Tiled software and check: 'Embed tileset' on each tileset of the map.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and the problem is that you must click "embed tileset" button in Tiled program.

Well it seems easy... but you must click on it, then click on FIle > export as > Json Map.

But make sure you just cliecked on it before the manipulation. If you make any change in Tiled after that... it doesn't embed the tile set.

To make sure your tileset is embed, look at the .json exported file. It should contains information about the tile set. Some properties like "name", etc.

```
 "tilesets":[
    {
     "columns":16,
     "firstgid":1,
     "image":"grassland_tiles.png",
     "imageheight":1344,
     "imagewidth":1024,
     "margin":0,
     "name":"grassland_tiles",
     "spacing":0,
     "tilecount":672,
     "tileheight":32,
     "tilewidth":64,
     "transparentcolor":"#ff00ff"
    }],
```